# How can I see this equation describes advection?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My notes say that this is the equation for the "advection of a quantity **A** at speed **v**":

$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t} = \nabla\times(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{A}) .$$

Is this true? How can I see (mathematically) that this equation corresponds to advection?

Comment: Is there any special property that $\mathbf{A}$ has to satisfy?

Comment: no, $\mathbf{A}$ is a general vector property. In my example it is the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$

Comment: Well, B does have special properties, such as always-zero divergence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This term looks like [Faraday's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_law_of_induction) that is used in [Ideal magnetohydrodynamics (MHD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamics#Ideal_MHD_equations). So yes, it is true.

In order to see the mathematical advection, you'll need to apply some [vector calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Vector_cross_product):

$$
\nabla\times\mathbf a\times\mathbf b = \mathbf a\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf b\right) - \mathbf b\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf a\right) + \left(\mathbf b\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf a - \left(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf b
$$
Then grouping the $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ terms,
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf a\times\mathbf b = \left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf b+ \mathbf b\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf a - \left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf a+\mathbf a\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf b
$$
which then reduces to give the advection equation in the form
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf A}{\partial t}=\nabla\times\mathbf v\times\mathbf A=\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf A\mathbf v^T - \mathbf v\mathbf A^T\right)\tag{1}
$$ 
This now gives us a time-derivative of vector $\mathbf A$ equal to the gradient of $\mathbf A$ times the vector velocity, $\mathbf v$, which is pretty much what your advection equation is supposed to be.

It's probably a little bit more easily seen in component form:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\begin{array}{c}A_x \\ A_y \\ A_z\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}A_xv_x -v_xA_x& A_xv_y-v_xA_y & A_xv_z-v_xA_z \\ A_yv_x-v_yA_x & A_yv_y-v_yA_y & A_yv_z-v_yA_z \\ A_zv_x-v_zA_x & A_zv_y-v_zA_y & A_zv_z-v_zA_z\end{array}\right)
$$
which reduces to
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\begin{array}{c}A_x \\ A_y \\ A_z\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & A_xv_y-v_xA_y & A_xv_z-v_xA_z \\ A_yv_x-v_yA_x & 0 & A_yv_z-v_yA_z \\ A_zv_x-v_zA_x & A_zv_y-v_zA_y & 0\end{array}\right)\tag{2}
$$
And, very neatly, you have yourself some divergence free terms in the zero's along the diagonal:
$$
\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}0+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(A_xv_y-A_yv_x\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(A_xv_z-v_xA_z\right)
$$

Now with regards to the actual question, how can we show that this is an advection equation. [Advection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection) simply is the transport of some material along a fluid flow. Usually this means that 
$$D_t\psi=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi+\mathbf u\cdot\nabla\psi=0,$$
where $\mathbf u$ is the velocity of the fluid flow. In the particular case that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf u=0$, then we can use 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi+\nabla\cdot(\mathbf u\psi)=0\tag{3}$$
which is the more-familiar continuity equation.

But that is for *scalar* advection. In the case considered here, we have a *vector* to advect. This is easily done by replacing the scalar $\psi$ with the vector $\mathbf a$ in Equation (3)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf a+\nabla\cdot(\mathbf u\mathbf a)=0$$
But we have this tricky $\mathbf{ua}$ term here. It can't be the dot product because divergence of a scalar is meaningless, so it must mean some other geometric product. In this case it makes a [dyad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyad_product):
$$
\mathbf{ua}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}u_xa_x & u_xa_y & u_xa_z \\ u_ya_x & u_ya_y & u_ya_z \\ u_za_x & u_za_y & u_za_z\end{array}\right)
$$
Taking the derivative of this matrix (a poor way to think of a tensor) gives you a vector. Thus, we should write this as
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf a+\nabla\cdot(\mathbf u\mathbf a^T)=0$$
to specify that we mean a tensor product there.

This now gives the form of Equation (1) that I claimed was an advection equation. The extra minus term in Equations (1) & (2) comes from the fact that your equation from Faraday's law contains a *vector **product*** of two terms which leads to *two* tensor products, rather than just one.

Comment: thanks, but how does this correspond to advection?
I thought advection meant 'transport', how is that translated mathematically?

Comment: Advection is the transport of some variable along a flow: $\partial_tq+\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{v}q)=0$. Faraday's law as given is an advection equation with a particular constraint that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$.

Comment: I know about the continuity equation, but $q$ is a scalar and $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity at which the fluid is moving. Here $\mathbf{B}$ is a vector quantity, how do I adjust the continuity equation?

Comment: Well you don't *adjust* the advection equation, you *derive* a new one. In the case of the magnetic field, the temporal evolution of the $\mathbf B$ field depends on the electric field, you then can use the Lorentz force law (assuming no forces) to get that $\mathbf E=\mathbf v\times\mathbf B$, thus $\partial_t\mathbf B=\nabla\times\mathbf v\times\mathbf B$.

Comment: The momentum conservation equation (another advection equation) takes the form $\partial_t(\rho\mathbf v)+\nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf v\mathbf v^T)=\nabla p$ where $p$ is the pressure.

Comment: Also: there are some minus sign errors in the above two comments.

Comment: where did you get the momentum conservation equation?

Comment: anyway I apologise but I really don't see how $\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf A\mathbf v^T - \mathbf v\mathbf A^T\right) $ corresponds to transport / advection

Comment: Momentum conservation comes from [the fluid dynamics equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)). I suppose I presumed you were familiar with it, given your question being about the $\mathbf B$ component of MHD.

Comment: I'm amending my answer to include more information on how the above is an advection equation.

Comment: @Harold: My answer has been amended. Let me know if this isn't enough for you :D

Comment: amazing this makes more sense. I was familiar with the momentum equation but I had always seen it in terms of the density $\rho$ and the velocity $\mathbf{u}$, and I had never seen a physical application of a dyad before. Thanks.

Comment: So basically in the end, does $( \mathbf {A}\mathbf {v^T} - \mathbf{v}\mathbf {A^T}) $ have a physical meaning?

Comment: @Harold: Just as $\rho\mathbf u$ is the mass flux in the continuity equation (how much mass flows through some surface), $\mathbf{Av}^T-\mathbf{vA}^T$ is the magnetic vector flux (how much magnetic field flows through some surface).

Comment: Just by definition? Or is there an intuitive way to see that it is a vector flux?

Comment: More or less by definition.